# Why ReportViewer in asp.net doesn't have RenderingComplete event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, report-viewer2010

I'm using ReportViewer in ASP.NET. In msdn it says that ReportViewer hase a RenderingComplete event. Here is the documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.reportviewer.renderingcomplete

But I can't find it in event list of ReportViewer in Visual Studio 2010. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no real "problem". This event only exists for the *WinForms* version of the ReportViewer. For the *WebForms* version there [is no analogous member](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.reportviewer_members). Since you mention you're using ASP.NET, you're using the latter ReportViewer

It wouldn't make sense for WebForms to have one, because events in the WebForms [work somewhat differently](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at2tetf6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) than in WinForms.

Comment: Actually I want to get ReportViewer.LocalReport.getTotalPages() when render completes. This method returns false before until the render is not complete.

Comment: Hmm, I don't quite understand: [that method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251848(v=vs.80).aspx) returns an `Int32`, never "false". Note that LocalReport in the *WebForms* ReportViewer doesn't mean that the report is run on your PC, but that it is processed on the web server (as opposed to on the Report Server).

Comment: sorry man. It returns 0. Really sorry for mistake. I understand what you say. How ever is there any way to know when the render is complete on the server side?

Comment: Okay, I see. Have a look at [this msdn thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsreportcontrols/thread/95672f99-a480-4cae-a583-50422a596f94/) about exactly that topic. Bottom line is that GetTotalPages can't be called until the ReportViewer has completed to Render. Note that things behave different depending on whether `AsyncRendering` is true or not.